# Deploying simple nodejs app to Heroku - Procfile not working

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Express server to my Heroku app, but every time I do, I get an error and it crashes.

I setup my `Procfile` with the following code: `web: node /src/server.js`

Where `server.js` is not in the root of the directory. However, when I try to start the server, I get an error in the logs: `Error: Cannot find module '/src/server.js'`

When I run the app locally, I have to run `npm start` in order for it to run the server correctly. Here is the relevant `"scripts"` portion of my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev nodemon ./src/server.js --exec babel-node",
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "babel ./src -d dist --presets es2015,stage-2 --ignore spec.js,node_modules",
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js",
    "start_babel": "babel-node ./server.js --preset=babel-preset-es2015",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  }
```

Since the Procfile overrides the package.json script commands, why is it having trouble finding my file when I've explicitly set it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the leading slash. Does using `./src/server.js` help at all?

Comment: Thanks for the response :) Unfortunately, I've tried that and when I do, I get an error saying Error: Cannot find module '/app/src/server.js'. Why is there an `app` folder to begin with?